# How to get OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in front of SpringSecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring-security, servlet-filters

I get a LazyInitializationException because the DelegatingFilterProxy from Spring Security is registered in front of the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.

I register the OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter like this in my AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer:

```java
@Override
protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    insertFilters(servletContext, new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
}
```

If I don't use the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer and register the filter in the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer like this

```java
@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    return new Filter[] { new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter(), new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain") };
}
```

it works, but I need the AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer to enable the HttpSessionEventPublisher.

How does one get OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter in front of SpringSecurityFilterChain?

A testcase can be found at https://github.com/bugix/spring-security-testcase